# Problem with saving checkbox values with WordPress Widget API

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I'm trying to learn WordPress Widget API. Everything looks great, except for the checkbox controls. Also, the `checked()` function puzzles me a bit, I'm confused about what value to propose if I have to default a checkbox unchecked.

Here's the bit of code I'm trying inside the Widget Class wrapper.

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
  extract( $args );
  $checkbox1 = ! empty( $instance['checkbox1'] ) ? $instance['checkbox1'] : false;
  $checkbox2 = ! empty( $instance['checkbox2'] ) ? $instance['checkbox2'] : false;
  $checkbox3 = ! empty( $instance['checkbox3'] ) ? $instance['checkbox3'] : false;

  echo $args['before_widget'];
  echo "Hello world, just testing this out.";
  echo $args['after_widget'];
}

public function form( $instance ) {

  $defaults = array(
    'checkbox1' => true,
    'checkbox2' => true,
    'checkbox3' => true,
  );

  $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); 
  ?>

<p>
  <input 
    class="checkbox" 
    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox1' ) ); ?>" 
    name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'checkbox1' ) ); ?>" 
    type="checkbox" 
    <?php checked( '1', $instance['checkbox1'] ); ?> 
    value="1">

  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox1' ) ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Checkbox #1', 'test' ); ?>
  </label> 
</p>

<p>
  <input 
    class="checkbox" 
    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox2' ) ); ?>" 
    name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'checkbox2' ) ); ?>" 
    type="checkbox" 
    <?php checked( '1', $instance['checkbox2'] ); ?> 
    value="1">

  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox2' ) ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Checkbox #2', 'test' ); ?>
  </label> 
</p>

<p>
  <input 
    class="checkbox" 
    id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox3' ) ); ?>" 
    name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'checkbox3' ) ); ?>" 
    type="checkbox" 
    <?php checked( '1', $instance['checkbox3'] ); ?> 
    value="1">

  <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'checkbox3' ) ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Checkbox #2', 'test' ); ?>
  </label> 
</p>

  <?php 
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

  $instance = $old_instance;

  $instance['checkbox1'] = isset( $new_instance['checkbox1'] ) ? 1 : false;
  $instance['checkbox2'] = isset( $new_instance['checkbox2'] ) ? 1 : false;
  $instance['checkbox3'] = isset( $new_instance['checkbox3'] ) ? 1 : false;

  return $instance;
}
```

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Update #2)*

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Gvd3UBvh)'s the full widget `class` that I previously shared via my *comment*. =)

In that `class`, the `checkbox1` field is default to *not* checked, while the rest of the `checkbox` fields are checked by default.

---

*(Update #1. Note that this update does not use your example code, but hopefully this answer would be of **more** help than the previous answer.)*

First off, `checkbox` fields (i.e. `<input type="checkbox">`), as you may already know, normally would be of two values — a "on" value (set if the `checkbox` field is *checked*), and a "off" value (set if the field is ***not*** checked).

So let's say you have a widget with the following default options, which are all `checkbox` fields:

```
$defaults = array(
  'cb1' => 'yes',
  'cb2' => 'no',
);
```

And for both of the fields, the "on" value is `yes`, while the "off" value is `no`.

Then in your widget options form, you display the `checkbox` fields using the following markup: (***other attributes such as `id` and `name` are intentionally not included***)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="{A}"<?php checked( '{B}', '{C}' ); ?>>
```

Where `{A}` and `{B}` are always the "on" value, whereas `{C}` is the value as it is *currently* in the database *or* in the `$defaults` array if the widget options have not yet been changed — e.g. the widget has just been added to a sidebar.

So if you look at the (above) sample `$defaults` array:

1. The `cb1` field would be *checked* by default, because the default value is the "on" value — `$defaults['cb1']` is `yes`.
2. The `cb2` field would be ***not*** checked by default, because the default value is the "off" value — `$defaults['cb2']` is `no`.

### Sample widget `class` for testing the `checkbox` fields: "My Widget"

```
<?php
class MY_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct( 'my_widget', 'My Widget', array(
            'classname'   => 'my-widget',
            'description' => 'Testing checkbox fields.',
        ) );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
            echo '<pre>'; var_dump( $instance ); echo '</pre>';
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['cb1'] = isset( $new_instance['cb1'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        $instance['cb2'] = isset( $new_instance['cb2'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

        return $instance;
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args(
            (array) $instance,
            // The default options.
            array(
                'cb1' => 'yes', // checked by default
                'cb2' => 'no',  // not checked by default
            )
        );
        ?>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cb1' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cb1' ); ?>" value="yes"<?php checked( 'yes', $instance['cb1'] ); ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cb1' ); ?>">Checkbox #1</label><br>

                <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cb2' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'cb2' ); ?>" value="yes"<?php checked( 'yes', $instance['cb2'] ); ?>>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'cb2' ); ?>">Checkbox #2</label>
            </p>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there, Sally CJ. Thanks for your answer, that was just sample code I prepared in a jiffy replacing those embarrassing prefixes and text domains. Please ignore that 'checkbox1' repeat, and check it at your end if it's working. I have already been following this approach.

Comment: Hi Bheemsen. Yes, it is working. Here's the full code I used: https://pastebin.com/CTewT5p9 Tried and tested on WordPress 4.9.8. The *only* changes are those in my answer, and that of course, my code is a full widget `class`.

Comment: Well, it's working fine here as well, dunno what I was missing! Was not using the selective fresh too. Thank you Sally, for taking time to help me. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Bheemsen I hope you don't mind that I edited my answer, and hopefully it will help you more. =)

Comment: Hello Sally, it's good to see you explaining it with an example. However, I noticed that only the default states are being shown in the front-end of the widget in each of my efforts, and it doesn't actually follow the logic (based on those checkboxes) that goes inside the `widget()` function. I tried once more with that neatly written example of yours, still I have no luck. I'll be back after trying a couple more times.

Comment: If you could post (on Pastebin, maybe) the full code of the *actual* widget `class` you used, perhaps I could help you identify the problems, if any. :) You can also add `var_dump( $instance );` right after the `function widget( $args, $instance ) { /* here */ ... }` and *before* the `return` statement in the `update()` function of your widget. Check also for typo in the field *names*.. it could happen just like when writing comments/questions/answers.. which I did just now and thus edited this comment.. ;)

Comment: This solution works very well. I extended it and added a loop to add more fields and check multiple checkboxes. Thanks !